# comparison of two sorted files by common first field

Tags: text-processing, awk, diff, hosts

I have to compare the IPs of two different `/etc/hosts` files and show a diff in side-by-side view.

File **hosts_sorted**

```
10.244.74.152   REF_UP-4
10.244.74.154   REF_UP-5
10.244.74.156   REF_UP-6
10.244.74.153   REF_UP-7
10.244.74.155   REF_UP-8
10.244.74.157   REF_UP-9
10.244.74.159   REF_UP-10
10.244.74.160   REF_UP-11
```

File **hosts_new_sorted**

```
10.244.74.152   REF_UP-4-new
10.244.74.154   REF_UP-5-new
10.244.74.156   REF_UP-6-new
10.244.74.153   REF_UP-7-new
10.244.74.155   REF_UP-8-new
10.244.74.157   REF_UP-9-new
10.244.74.160   REF_UP-11-new
```

And my expected output

```
< 10.244.74.159   REF_UP-10
```

I already sorted the entries by IP and used `diff <(cut -f1 hosts_sorted) <(cut -f1 hosts_new_sorted)`. Howwever, this cuts out the hostnames which are needed. Is there a way to tell diff only to use the first column? However the comparison shall not include the second column.

Comment: In what way is `diff hosts_sorted hosts_new_sorted` not doing what you want?

Comment: It also compares the second column (hostname in `/etc/hosts/`)

Comment: what about if you had a host which only and only exist in host_new_sorted like `10.244.74.162   REF_UP-12-new`? you don't want that line then as your accepted answer is only doing checking in one direction meaning that print those lines that _that host_ only and only exist in host_sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' hosts_new_sorted hosts_sorted
10.244.74.159   REF_UP-10
```

it will check the presence of the first column of `hosts_sorted` in `hosts_new_sorted`, prints if not available.

Comment: It works only in one direction. That's enough?